# FileNotFoundException, URL connection error, Babelfy, Java

Tags: java

This sample program from [Babelfy](http://babelfy.org/home) was working fine for a day and when I ran it the next day I was getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://babelfy.org/rest?text=He%20has%20a%20passion%20for%20music&key=%20&partMatching=false&lang=EN&format=json
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy.babelfy(Babelfy.java:95)
    at Example.main(Example.java:19)

Example is the name of the Java program.

Here's the code:

```
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy.Matching;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.Babelfy.AccessType;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.data.Annotation;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.data.BabelSynsetAnchor;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelSense;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelSynset;
import it.uniroma1.lcl.jlt.util.Language;

public class Example 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Babelfy bfy = Babelfy.getInstance(AccessType.ONLINE);
    BabelNet bn = BabelNet.getInstance();
    String word=" ";
    String inputText = "He has a passion for music";
    Annotation annotations = bfy.babelfy(" ", inputText, Matching.EXACT, Language.EN);
    System.out.println("inputText: "+inputText+"\nannotations:");
    for(BabelSynsetAnchor annotation : annotations.getAnnotations())
    {
        word=annotation.getBabelSynset().getId();
        System.out.println(annotation.getAnchorText()+"\t"+word+"\t"+annotation.getBabelSynset());
        //BabelSynset by = bn.getSynsetFromId(("bn:03083790n"));
    for (BabelSense sense : bn.getSynsetFromId((word))) 
     {
        if(sense.getSource().toString().equals("WN"))
            System.out.println("Sense: " + sense.getLemma()+ "\tSource: " + sense.getSource().toString());
     }
    }

}   
}
```

I have added the libraries of both 0.9 and 1.0 version Babelfy in the build path of my Eclipse project?

Can anybody find the nature of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Babelfy-API is outdated. It tries to connect to http://babelfy.org/rest, which [is not available (anymore)](http://babelfy.org/guide).

Version 1.0 is still the current version, so please remove your 0.9 version. Java might choose the first version it finds which would probably be 0.9.

After removing the 0.9.jar, you should be able to make a proper API call.

Comment: Thank you. I got it clarified a little while ago though. I arrived at the same solution.